# Frequency response of $\mathrm{sinc}[n]$

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, lowpass-filter, frequency-response

In this image the frequency response of a discrete time filter given as $h[n]$. Can someone explain how the magnitude of the frequency response is found ?[image]

Comment: Have you studied Z-transforms?

Comment: There's a typo in the definition of $h[n]$; there shouldn't be a $t$ in the denominator but an $n$! This is a basic Fourier transform pair: sinc <=> rect. It's easier to start from the rectangular spectrum and go back to the time domain via an inverse DTFT. Then remember that relation both ways.

Comment: @panthyon: Z-transform won't help here, because the given $h[n]$ doesn't have a Z-transform. This is one of the cases where the Fourier transform can be used but the Z-transform can't. People always say that the Fourier transform is a special case of the Z-transform, but this is not entirely true (as shown by this example).

Comment: @Matt Now I'm confused, how can there not be a z-transform? The Discrete Fourier Transform is a special case (sub-space perhaps more accurately) of the Z-transform, evaluated on the unit circle and the Fourier Transform is a special case of the Laplace Transform, evaluated on the $j\omega$ axis.  But the z-transform itself (evaluated everywhere) should exist, no?  Is it because n is going to infinity?  I believe the z transform converges for all |z|>1

Comment: @DanBoschen: The given $h[n]$ is a two-sided sequence, so the ROC of the Z-transform must be a ring $a<|z|<b$. However, in this case there are no constants $a$ and $b$ such that the sum converges in such a ring. The sum only converges (in a generalized sense) for $|z|=1$, but that's the Fourier transform, not the Z-transform (which needs to converge in a ring, or outside/inside a circle). Same for the Laplace transform. Impulse responses of ideally frequency selective filters have no Laplace transform but a Fourier transform.

Comment: Same for sinusoids. There is no Laplace transform of the function $\sin(\omega_0t)$, but there is a Fourier transform (using Dirac deltas). (Note that we're not talking about the function $\sin(\omega_0t)u(t)$.)

Comment: @MattL Interesting, thanks for the explanation. I would have thought the convergence on |z|=1 (or equivalently the $j\omega$ in Laplace) would have counted as a solution in those domains but do see how they must be impulses as opposed to the exponential surface around poles due to the u[n] and u(t), so never really thought through that case, nor do I recall ever seeing impulses as the solution in Laplace or z so that all makes sense.  Prior to this I was always thinking that Laplace/z had the solutions when FT didn't, so this is an interesting twist (for me). Thanks!

Comment: @DanBoschen: Yes, there are cases where Laplace/Z-transforms exist but Fourier doesn't (which everybody knows about), but there are also cases where only Fourier exists but not Laplace/Z (which not everybody seems to realize), even though everybody is so used to working with ideal filters or ideal sinusoids :)

Comment: @Matt L. Does it matter that instead of $\sin x / x$ we have $\sin \frac{x}{2} / x $?

Comment: @panthyon: The two are different, obviously, but it doesn't matter when it comes to convergence of the Z-transform or Fourier transform. Note that $\sin(x/2) / x=\frac12\sin(x/2)/(x/2)$

Comment: that identity helped me a lot when i did this out on paper, thanks!

Comment: @MattL what about the 2 sided Laplace Transform; does something disallow impulses on the frequency axis from being a solution in that case?

Comment: @DanBoschen: Everything said so far was about the bilateral Laplace (Z-) transform, because the function / sequence is two-sided. Note that the distribution $\delta(\omega)$ can't be a Laplace transform.

Comment: @Matt (sorry I am so confused) So why can't impulses on the unit circle or $j\omega$ axis be a viable solution then as the z and Laplace transforms even though it is just a line and not a region of convergence; is it strictly because of just that: a region with non-zero width is necessary for the Transform to exist, because of convention or is there more to it than that?

Comment: @Matt ok it's a little clearer to me now, remembering that the ROC is bounded by but does not include the poles- with that I can see that a line cannot exist, at least a line with the poles on it. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: @Matt How can I see that the function does not have a Z transform just by looking at the function? And I have studied Z transforms.

Comment: @Jawad: The DTFT is discontinuous, which implies that the Z-transform doesn't exist.

Comment: I am confused what do you mean by continuos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is a mistake in that image: there should be an $n$ in the denominator instead of a $t$.

Check that your signal can be expressed as

$$h[n]=2\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}n\right)}{\pi n}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}n\right)}{\frac{\pi}{2}n} \tag{1}$$.

Using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry) we can express that sine as the sum of two exponentials:

$$h[n]=\frac{1}{\pi/2}\frac12\frac{e^{jn\pi/2}-e^{-jn\pi/2}}{jn}=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{e^{jn\pi/2}-e^{-jn\pi/2}}{jn}$$

Let me multiply and divide that expression by $2$, which doesn't change anything but will be useful later:

$$h[n]=\frac{1}{2\pi}2\frac{e^{jn\pi/2}-e^{-jn\pi/2}}{jn} \tag{2}$$

Notice that there exists an integral that returns that exact function of $n$ and, on top of it, that integral represents the inverse Fourier transform of some function:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}2e^{j\omega n} \ \mathrm{d}\omega=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[H(e^{j\omega})]=h[n] \tag{3}$$

where $H(e^{j\omega})$ is periodic in $2\pi$ and, for each period:

$$H(e^{j\omega}) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  2  & \mbox{if } |\omega| \leq \pi/2 \\
  0 &   \ \mathrm{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.$$

So the Fourier transform of $h[n]$ is $H(e^{j\omega})$, because the inverse Fourier transform of the latter is the former. And that's the proof.

However, most of the times one does not do all these calculations and just [looks up the transform of $\mathrm(1)$](http://pfister.ee.duke.edu/courses/ece485/dtft_table.pdf). (In the link's table, look up for your signal and replace $W=2$. Then use the linearity of the Fourier transform to get to the result you are looking for.)